# How do I add referrer data in query params or link data in Branch io link?

Tags: branch.io

Suppose I have placed a branch link on my website example.com/outer/inner. This link leads to another web app. I need to know that the link was clicked on example.com/outer/inner.
How do I get this information?

Answer (score 1):

You can add analytical tags to your original link that will indicate the source of the click. Please check https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link#analytical-labels

You can add these labels when creating the link and if you want to append it to an existing link you can add additional analytical label as link query parameters, check the doc on Branch long links here https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link#long-links

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I could figure out that you can add the referrer as a parameter but that is only useful if you use the branch link at one place.
Branch can not identify the link on its own.